# Styling html table to be responsive and vertical scrolling

Tags: html, css, html-table

Basically here's a table. I want it responsive (not to viewport, just to browser width. I don't want fixed px width), and I want it scrolling.

But as you can see it's doing weird stuff in the tbody part. I don't know why it's not taking the full width...

How do I fix that?

Btw, the first column (Color) has colspan="2" attribute, just so you know.

**I found a way to fix it thanks to css calc() function and some basic maths.**

```css
table {
    margin: 0% 5%;
    width: 90%;
    color: black;
    font-family: Consolas;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
tbody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
td, th {
  padding: 4px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

tbody, thead, tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
th.special {
  width: calc( 29% - 0.29*17px + 17px);
}
td.A {width: 14%;}
td.B {width: 29%;} 
td.C {width: 43%;}
th.A {width: calc(14% - 0.14*17px); }
th.B {width: calc(29% - 0.29*17px); } 
th.C {width: calc(43% - 0.43*17px);}
td.color { background-color: #FE33E9; }
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th class="C" colspan="2">Color</th><th class="A">X</th><th class="A">Y</th><th class="special">Caption</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td class="B">FE33E9</td><td class="A">121</td><td class="A">433</td><td class="B">bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td class="B">FE33E9</td><td class="A">121</td><td class="A">433</td><td class="B">bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td class="B">FE33E9</td><td class="A">121</td><td class="A">433</td><td class="B">bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td class="B">FE33E9</td><td class="A">121</td><td class="A">433</td><td class="B">bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td class="B">FE33E9</td><td class="A">121</td><td class="A">433</td><td class="B">bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td class="B">FE33E9</td><td class="A">121</td><td class="A">433</td><td class="B">bottom</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [Make tables responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_table_responsive)

Comment: I don't want horizontal scrolling. I found that ugly. I'd rather have auto adjusting column width

Comment: Posted updated answer may be it will work for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help you with markup and code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: At what point did I ask for people to write me code? The code is already written, I want help to fix it. Isn't it the point of stack overflow? Helping fix common unintended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `calc` width to get it, still you have to write some `media query` to get proper responsive table.

Update css part

```
td {
  width: calc(100% / 5 - 8px);
}

th {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0% 5%;
  width: 90%;
  color: black;
  font-family: Consolas;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table tbody tr {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 4px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  width: calc(100% / 5 - 8px);
}

th {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}


/* th.A, td.A {width: 14%;}
th.B, td.B {width: 29%;} 
th.C, td.C {width: 43%;} */

td.color {
  background-color: #FE33E9;
}

table tbody {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="C" colspan="2">Color</th>
      <th class="A">X</th>
      <th class="A">Y</th>
      <th class="B">Caption</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="A color">.</td>
      <td class="B">FE33E9</td>
      <td class="A">121</td>
      <td class="A">433</td>
      <td class="B">bottom</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="A color">.</td>
      <td class="B">FE33E9</td>
      <td class="A">121</td>
      <td class="A">433</td>
      <td class="B">bottom</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="A color">.</td>
      <td class="B">FE33E9</td>
      <td class="A">121</td>
      <td class="A">433</td>
      <td class="B">bottom</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="A color">.</td>
      <td class="B">FE33E9</td>
      <td class="A">121</td>
      <td class="A">433</td>
      <td class="B">bottom</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="A color">.</td>
      <td class="B">FE33E9</td>
      <td class="A">121</td>
      <td class="A">433</td>
      <td class="B">bottom</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="A color">.</td>
      <td class="B">FE33E9</td>
      <td class="A">121</td>
      <td class="A">433</td>
      <td class="B">bottom</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I did not know about calc, is it a recommended usage? Or should it be avoided?

Comment: Yes it's  css3 property and you can read it  here
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Ok, you got me out thanks to calc. I just made it so that the thead if 100% - the scrollbar width (17px apparently). It aligns perfectly, I just need to fix border but it's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `tr` also a `width: 100%`.

This should work:

```
table tbody tr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Edited the snippet. That fixed one problem, but now the scrollbar is preventing the columns from aligning...

Answer (score 0):

You are given the display as inline-block, it means it will take the content space only , so give the display style as block, it will fully take the width.

```
//Here is the Updated CSS

table {
   margin: 0% 5%;
   width: 90%;
   color: black;
   font-family: Consolas;
   border-spacing: 0;
}
table, td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
td, th {
   padding: 4px 0px;
   display:inline-block;
}


th.A, td.A {width: 14%;}
th.B, td.B {width: 29%;} 
th.C, td.C {width: 43%;}
td.color {
  background-color: #FE33E9;
}

table tbody {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   /*Updated*/
   //overflow-y: auto;
   //overflow-x: hidden; //these No Need just give overflow as auto;
   overflow : auto;
}

//Newly Added

tr {
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-family: Consolas;
  border-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td {
  width: 5%;
}

.fth {
  width: 6.4%;
}

.sth {
  width: 3.1%;
}

.tth {
  width: 3.1%;
}

.foth {
  width: 3%;
}

td.color {
  background-color: #FE33E9;
}

table thead {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

table tbody {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="table-1">
   <thead id="header-fixed">
       <tr style=""><th colspan="2" class="fth">Color</th><th class="sth">X</th><th class="tth">Y</th><th class="foth">Caption</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="A color">.</td><td>FE33E9</td><td>121</td><td>433</td><td>bottom</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

i have edit code for see `thead` when `tbody` scroll

**now it work properly using `css`**

Comment: That's a really nice one, although I would like to keep the headings while scrolling. That's why the scrollbar was only on the tbody

Comment: It's a really nice solution, I quite like it but I found another way of doing it with css calc function. I will keep that aside though, thank you

Comment: @Philippe check it now its work properly using `css`

Comment: Wow it is almost perfect and really efficient. The head and the body borders don't line up perfectly :p